# Cgi-bin script to cat a file owned by a user

Tags: linux, apache, bash, file-permissions, cgi-bin

I'm using Ubuntu server and I have a cgi-bin script doing the following . . .

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type: text/plain
echo ""
cat /home/user/.program/logs/file.log | tail -400  | col -b > /tmp/o.txt
cat /tmp/o.txt
```

Now if I run this script with I am "su" the script fills o.txt and then the host.com/cgi-bin/script runs but only shows up to the point I last ran it from the CLI

My apache error log is showing "permission denied" errors. So I know the user apache is running under somehow cannot cat this file. I tried using chown to no avail. Since this file is in a user directory, what is the best way to either duplicate it or symbolic link it or what?

I even considered running the script as root in a crontab to sort of "update" the file in /tmp/ but that did not work for me. How would somebody experienced with cgi-bin handle access to a file in a users directory?

Comment: Running `tail -n 400 logfile | sudo -u www-data tee /var/www/tail.txt >/dev/null` once per minute would obviate the need for a CGI script in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The Apache user `www-data` does not have write access to a temporary file owned by another user.

But in this particular case, no temporary file is required.

```
tail -n 400 logfile | col -b
```

However, if Apache is running in a restricted `chroot`, it also has no access to `/home`.

The log file needs to be `chmod o+r` and all directories leading down to it should be `chmod o+x`.  Make sure you understand the implications of this!  If the user has a reason to want to prevent access to an intermediate directory, having read access to the file itself will not suffice. (Making something have `www-data` as its group owner is possible in theory, but impractical and pointless, as anybody who finds the CGI script will have access to the file anyway.)

More generally, if you do need a temporary file, the simple fix (not even workaround) is to generate a unique temporary file name, and remove it afterwards.

```
temp=$(mktemp -t cgi.XXXXXXXX) || exit $?
trap 'rm -f "$temp"' 0
trap 'exit 127' 1 2 15

tail -n 400 logfile | col -b >"$temp"
```

The first `trap` makes sure the file is removed when the script terminates. The second makes sure the first `trap` runs if the script is interrupted or killed.

Comment: I tried using just tail by itself and here is the new error in my apache error log

 tail: cannot open `/home/user/.program/log' for reading: Permission denied

Comment: The signal numbers in `trap` should properly be symbolic. Too old and lazy to look them up. EXIT and ... something anf HUP and INT I guess?

Comment: Does the user know and approve of this? Then getting permissions granted and/or the file moved to a more accessible location should be a simple matter.

Comment: yes the user is my user, the file is a log created by a program in userland that should not be run as root. Is there an easy way to copy that file live as it grows to a location apache can access? I was thinking crontab but you may know an easier way.

Comment: Having the file in a sane place to begin with is probably better.  Note the recent update re: permissions on directories.

Comment: You did it , I have no idea what the o+r and o+x do but I will read up on it. I thought having chmod 777 would suffice but I guess not.

Comment: You know it is producing something now but it is actually an old part of the log and when the log updates and i refresh the page the page stays the same. I have no idea.

Comment: I am the only user on the server, just root and my user, is chmod 777 still a bad idea?

Comment: Ok so this actually works but only once, then every time i go to update the page it only loads the original cat of the log, it won't repeat the process. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to change the program that creates the log in the first place and write it to some place visible to Apache - maybe through symbolic links.

For example:

```
ln -s /var/www/cgi-bin/logs /home/user/.program/logs
```

So your program continues to write to `/home/user/.program/logs` but the data actually lands in `/var/www/cgi-bin/logs` where Apache can read it.

Comment: If the final destination is not permitted, Apache will not be able to traverse the symlink, either.  Otherwise it would be trivial to obtain access to stuff you are blocked from!

Comment: Apache doesn't need to use the symlink. The OP's original program writes via the symlink, Apache reads the real file. Sorry, I had the link back-to-front.

Comment: symbolic links make sense to me, i thought that might be the way, I ran the equiv of the logic on my system but ln said "failed to create, file exists." Sorry I have no idea, sometimes the cgi script runs btw . . . I am confused.

Comment: You need to move the old file aside, or run `ln -fs` to force it.  That will overwrite any existing log, though.